# Имеет ли смысл последовательно оборачивать в try-catch ряд функций?

Tags: c#, оптимизация, исключения, try-catch

```
try { File.Delete(info); } catch { }
try { File.Delete(path + ".exe"); } catch { }
try { File.Move(path + ".old.exe", path + ".exe"); } catch { }
try { Process.Start(path + ".exe"); } catch { }
```

Можно ли объединить обёртку такого кода в один `try-catch`?

Завершится ли код в случае, если не удастся удалить `info`, или он продолжит выполнение?

Comment: ON ERROR RESUME NEXT!

Answer (score 5):

Смысла в таком коде мало: ведь если не удалось удалить .exe, то перемещать на его место другой файл - бесполезно даже пытаться. Ну и запускать программу не смотря на то, старый файл там или новый - неосмотрительно.

В вашем случае как раз лучше остановиться после первой же ошибки. Именно такое поведение будет у единого блока `try`. Ну и надо не забывать обрабатывать исключение - вряд ли пользователь скажет вам спасибо если программа будет "втихую" ничего не делать.

Comment: Может ему так и надо. Новая программа хорошо, а старая ещё лучше!

Answer (score 2):

Если в catch-и добавить специальные обработки и отмену дельнейшего выполнения (например, return), то смысл появится.

Заметьте, что лучше сделать так, чтобы ошибка не возникала. То есть сперва проверить существует ли файл и только затем если он существует попробовать его удалить.

Если нет желания заморачиваться. то можно объединить и в один блок try-catch

Comment: Между проверкой существования файла и его удалением всегда есть промежуток времени, когда его успеет удалить кто-то другой. Так что вероятность исключения никак не меняется.Обработчик нужен в любом случае. Так стоит ли тратить усилия на лишнюю проверку, которая и так выполняется сама собой во время удаления?

Comment: *"Заметьте, что лучше сделать так, чтобы ошибка не возникала. То есть сперва проверить существует ли файл и только затем если он существует попробовать его удалить."* При попытке удалить несуществующий файл ошибки не возникает!

Comment: Обработчик нужен (файл кроме того может быть заблокирован), но все должны быть согласны, что лучше не допустить возникновения ошибки.